# How to make snippet suggestion case-sensitive in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VScode,Snippet suggestion sorted in order to Find character in prefix body.

[image: example]

I do not want *fs.readFile* in suggest(Because **I want snippet suggestion case-sensitive**)

**Note:** Basically It's not a problem.But I use many custom snippet,so It appears with unusual timing.(So It is a big problem to me!)

Is there any setting in Vscode? Or any solution?

Comment: Not sure i understand but do you have `  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",` in your settings?

Comment: No.its "Inline".

Comment: Hey Nur. Having your suggestions case-sensitive doesn't make fs.readFile disappear because it does contain ".re" in the same lower case. Do you mean you want to _remove_ suggestions that don't start with `.re`?

Comment: No.I don't mean that any thing with *fs.readFile*.I want snippet match case-sensitively.Also,If  **.re** match is in a match rule than It's fine! But other should match correctly. DO you have any solution?

Comment: Example : Do you notice ***.every*** or ***fs.writeFile*** in suggestion,I want to rid of It.DO you have any solution? Thank you